# Can one change the datetime an item was added to a sprint?

Tags: jira

Can one change the datetime an item was added to a sprint?
Right now the scope change is recorded when it is done, but i would like to pretend an item was in the sprint all along.
Does this functionality exist anywhere?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to change the date or time on a scrum board, however you will need admin permissions on the project.

Here's a [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Editing+or+Reordering+a+Sprint) with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No :)

sorry but if we look at the understanding of a sprint its fine to add and remove items but what you are doing is manipulating the stats probably to improve your burndown?

I would advise against this.

Good luck in your endeavors :)